# Google application engine Datastore - any alternatives to aggregate functions and group by?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

As is mentioned in the doc for google app engine, it does not support group by and other aggregation functions. Is there any alternatives to implement the same functionality?

I am working on a project where I need it on urgent basis, being a large database its not efficient to iterate the result set and then perform the logic.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to populate the summaries (aggregates) at the time of write. This way your reads will be faster, since they just read - at the cost of writes which will have to update the summaries if its likely to be effected by the write.

Hopefully you will be reading more often than writing/updating summaries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ashwin, so you mean for now there is no way using Datastore API to perform this functionality and we need to implement the logic ourselves instead ?

Comment: In the current state, yes. Your best bet is in maintaining all the summaries yourself. If generating summaries is a expensive task you may consider Task Queues as an option.